# What is the probability that 24 or more from this sample are freshman?

Tags: probability

> A math class has $140$ students of which $55\%$ are freshman. A random sample of $40$ students was
>   selected. What is the probability that $24$ or more from this sample are freshman?

What I have tried is $0.55*24/40=0.33$ which is not right. I don't see how to get the right solution.

Comment: Have a look at [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution). To be found is $\Pr(X\geq24)$.

Answer (score 0):

You have $140$ students, out of which, $140\cdot55/100=77$ are freshmen.

Let X denote the number of freshmen when choosing $40$ students.

Then $P(24\leq{X}\leq40)=\sum\limits_{n=24}^{40}\frac{\binom{77}{n}\cdot\binom{140-77}{40-n}}{\binom{140}{40}}\approx28.71\%$.